# Fullpage.js - Adding sections of normal content in between 'slides'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

Fullpage.js works perfect for everything I'll need for this project.  Need to have full page sized slides with a background image & a bit of bold text.

But then, between each full size slide, I need to have plain content (not full page) with additional information.

The 'one section' in the examples seems like exactly what I need, however that doesn't allow for anything fullpage.js after it.

I've disabled autoscrolling, so that isn't a concern.  Just can't figure out how to add 'normal HTML sections' in between each slide.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is not suppose to work that way. 
The more you could do is to use `scrollOverflow` as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

But, if you want a workaround, I made this ugly hack:

```
var cont = 0;

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
     afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){

        if(index == 2 && !cont){
            cont++;
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
            $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);

            var dTop = $('#fullpage').find('#section2').position().top;
            $('#fullpage').css('top', -dTop);

           $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },1);
        }
     },
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/800/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer above, however after trying a few different things I found a simple solution.  Instead of messing around with individual slides / sections, I just turned the #fullpage into a class and used it multiple times.

You can technically just use the ID multiple times without making any other changes and it'd work, but that's against convention so I made the other changes for it to recognize .fullpage instead.
I.e.

```html
<div class="fullpage">
 <div class="section" id="section1"><h1>Full Page 'Section'</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="plainContentHere">
 Any HTML can be entered here
</div>
<div class="fullpage">
 <div class="section" id="section2"><h1>Another Full Page 'Section'</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="plainContentHere">
 Any HTML can be entered here
</div>
```

It seems that fullpage was meant to be a singular container, but with autoScroll set to off, seems to work just as I needed.